# Android onActivityResult returns different code

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using starting my Intent with code 291 and result always comes in with status OK and code 131363. I don't have such nr. anywhere in my code. What could be causes for this?

If I start with code 294 it gives result 131366

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    CL.v("start for result " + type);
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, type);
    } else if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, type);
    } else if (appFragment != null) {
        appFragment.startActivityForResult(intent, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you post a part of your code that produces this. no one can help you.

Comment: That's the thing, this code is the same as always. For some reason it adds 131072 to every Intent request code. I have checked it 10x times nothing unusual. I just hoped this is known issue as usual with strange android bugs

Answer (score 1):

If you call startActivityForResult from the `Fragment` the result will deliver to the `Fragment`. And if you call startActivityForResult from the `Activity` the result will deliver to the `Activity`.

If you want to get the result in your Fragment try to change: `activity.startActivityForResult(intent, type);` to `startActivityForResult(intent, type);`

And remove all `if` statements.

Comment: But I get result in my MainActivity, regardless if I start it on fragment or not. I get result but for some reason it has +131366

Comment: @somerandomusername Well, try to call `activity.startActivityForResult(intent, type);`. It should works.

Comment: @somerandomusername When `Fragment` calls `StartActivityForResult` the `requestCode` will be changed by the `Activity`, so it will know how to deliver the result to which `Fragment`.